# c# changing name of controls in for loop

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a program that will make buttons on the screen from a for loop. This is important because the user needs to have access to the number of buttons, and could change with every run. This is the code i have so far:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int top = 5;
        int left = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Height = 50;
            button.Left = left;
            button.Top = top;
            this.Controls.Add(button);
            left += button.Width + 2;
        }
    }
```

What i want is basically something like this:

```
Button b+i = new Button();
```

Its like when combining two strings, i want the name of the button on the first run in the loop to be b0, then b1, then b2, and so on.

I use Visual Studio, and InitializeComponent() goes to the editor generated code to make the window and stuff. nothing but the window is made there.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can use `button.Name` to set a name like `string.Format("button{0}", i)`, also you can put `i` in `tag` and use it when you need.

Comment: You're not asking about setting the button's **name**. You're asking about changing the name of the variable that is holding the button instance, and you can't do that at runtime. Use an array to contain the buttons, and then you can reference them by index.

Comment: You may find this Q/A helpful: [Dynamic button creation & placing them in a predefined order using c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426888/dynamic-button-creation-placing-them-in-a-predefined-order-using-c-sharp)

Comment: Is the question answered in comments?

Comment: @RezaAghaei yes, using what was given by you, KenWhite, and MitchWheat i was able to figure it out. the following link will also summarize things with the concepts provided by you guys. [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d037902a-d79e-4d6d-b079-766ee69c0724/button-array-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral) for future people with the same concern

Comment: Good job :) Also consider using a `TableLayoutPanel` or `FlowLayoutPanel` if you want to layout your dynamic buttons simply. If you need a table-like layout, use `TableLayoutPanel`, if you need a flow layout, use `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Comment: THank you everyone you're all so amazing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Worrying about the variable names is the **wrong way** to approach this problem. There are several alternatives:

Use a list

```
List<Button> buttons;    

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    buttons = new List<Button>();
    int top = 5;
    int left = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Height = 50;
        button.Left = left;
        button.Top = top;
        this.Controls.Add(button);
        buttons.Add(button);
        left += button.Width + 2;
    }
}
//now instead of 'b1', it's 'buttons[1]'
```

Which you could also create with the OfType() method:

```
var buttons = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();
```

These can be done in combination with a FlowLayoutPanel or TableLayoutPanel to simplify the code:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Height = 50;
        FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(button); //panel handles Left/Top location
    }
}
```

The panel also has the advantage of helping your app scale at different dpi's or screen/window sizes.

Any of which could also be adapted to start thinking in terms of connecting to a datasource (and reduce the code):

```
var buttons = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(b => new Button {
   Height = 50,
   Left = 5 + ( b * (BUTTONWIDTH + 2) ),
   Top = 5,
   Name = String.Format("Button{0}", b)
});

//buttons.ToList()
//or
//this.Controls.AddRange(buttons.ToArray())
//or 
//FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.AddRange(buttons.ToArray()) //Remove Left/Top code
```

But all of this is meaningless until you can get the buttons to actually *do something*. You need an event handler for (at least) the Click event:

```
foreach (var b in butons)
{
     b.Click += (s,e) => 
    { 
        //click code for all of the buttons goes here
        // you can tell the buttons apart by looking at the "s" variable 

    };
}
```

Comment: Both are legal. Scroll down on the [docs page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) for object and list initializers and you'll see the example.

Comment: Oops, thought it was only legal when you used a parametized constructor. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: if i could "vote" for this answer a thousand times i would. This is so amazing. You're so amazing. thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

since people (rightly) said 'use an array' here is code

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        int top = 5;
        int left = 5;
        var buttons = new Button[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Height = 50;
            button.Left = left;
            button.Top = top;
            this.Controls.Add(button);
            left += button.Width + 2;
            buttons[i] = button;
        }
    }
```