# how to create a n*m board, where n and m are determined by the user

Tags: winforms

I want to create a board that the size of it will be determined by the user.
Is there a more simple way then using pictureBox[,] with a for loop inside a for loop?

Comment: You can use `TableLayoutPanel` like this [Dynamic button creation & placing them in a predefined order using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426888/dynamic-button-creation-placing-them-in-a-predefined-order-using-c-sharp). Also you can use a `DataGridView` having some `DataGridViewImageColumn`.

Comment: Or perhaps the data repeater control from the Visual Basic PowerPack.

Comment: well, if all rows are the same, you could generate a row with m columns and clone it n times, which saves the inner loop.