# How to access the txt info inside a ToolTip from a programmatically created button?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, button, tooltip

I have problems to access the string inside a programmatically created button.  Have a program which reads from a database and shows in a visual form, with buttons, the info of a specific process. Afterwards I want to make available this info with a "click" and show it in a window of the Form.

I create the button (boton1) programmatically, reading registers in a database (the number of buttons created depends of the registers and their values), and in the same step I create a new nutton I create their Tooltip (Tooltip1). So at the end I have a grid of buttons where I can see their tooltips if I haver the mouse over them. What I need is to be able to press these buttons and show in a textbox the info of these specific button's tooltip. The problem is because the boton1 creation is inside a method which creates the grid it's not accesible (I think this is the reason) from a method_click so the button (boton1) or Tooltip1 doesn't exists inside the button_click event, and if I create them it doesn't show when I click the Tooltip1 info but an empty string...

This is my code with the empty string, it doesn't show the info I see in the tooltips but "..." when I "click" on them.

```
protected void boton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ToolTip Tooltip1 = new ToolTip();  
    //This Tooltip is already created in other part of the code but without the code "running" don't exist for the button event creation
    Button boton1 = sender as Button;
    //Same here, already working and the tooltips seems fine but don't exist in the button_click event

    //identify which button was clicked and perform necessary actions
    String txtTool = tool.GetToolTip(button);
    String info = Tooltip1.GetToolTip(boton1);
}
```

Comment: Where did you create the `ToolTip`, Where did you create the `Button` and what to you want to do exactly. It's unclear what you are asking. If you have a correct reference for your button and your tooltip and if you've assigned to tooltip for button, `toolTip.GetToolTip(button)` should do the trick for you.

Comment: True, I will try and explain myself better. I create the button (boton1) programmatically  reading registers in a database (the number of buttons created depends of the registers and their values) and in the same step I create a new nutton I create their Tooltip (Tooltip1).  So I have working a Form where

Comment: Sorry Reza it was too long for a comment, I just edit the main question, thank you for your help :)

Comment: You will find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34426939/3110834) useful. It shows how to assign name to controls. Also handle click event of them. Also you can put some additional information in `Tag` property of your buttons and use it later.

Comment: Thank you Reza, I will look at it! :)

Comment: Thank you Reza but it seems the Tooltip property is not something we can reach, is not referenciable or something. So at the end I keep the Tooltip as it is and used the "Button.Text" property which yes, you can reference to store the information and it worked. another thing that maybe should work is with the "tag property" of the button but I didn't try that one.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not clear for me what you are exactly trying to achieve, if it was, I could post a simple code to do the job. I'm sure it's pretty simple :)