# String to existing object

Tags: c#, button, methods

So i have my buttons like this :

```
text : Skarl, Name : btnHeroe1 
text : Kled, Name : btnHeroe2 
text : Kled, Name : btnHeroe3
```

My object are like this (price, damage)

```
Heroe Heroe1 = new Heroe(100,5);
Heroe Heroe2 = new Heroe(500,10);
Heroe Heroe3 = new Heroe(100,40);
```

They have properties (price,dps,level)
And when i click on my button, i use this method with these lines to get the name of the button pressed :

```
Button b = sender as Button;
string vButton = b.Name;
string strHeroeToBuy = vButton.Substring(3, vButton.Length - 3);
```

Now i'm asking. How can i get the properties like this : strHeroeToBuy.Price ?
Edit : Solved it by getting the id of my heroes and searching with button have the same id

Comment: Use named parameters; you won't have to explain :)

Comment: Have a unique property in the Hero class,  that will help you identify the Hero. And store that in the Tag property of the button. Also have a List/ Array/ Collection of Hero that is used to create the Button based on listed Heros.

Comment: @Self even better, store the Hero instance in the Tag property of the button. Tag can be every object, you are not forced to set it with a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep your heroes in a list, and give them unique ids then you can find them:

```
// The id can be an int or a string, it's your choice
Heroes = new List<Heroe> { 
  new Heroe(id: 1, 100,5),
  new Heroe(id: 2, 500,10),
  new Heroe(id: 3, 100,40)
};

(...)

var id = //get Id from button 

// needs 'using System.Linq'
var myHero = Heroes.FirstOrDefault( h => h.Id == id); 

if(myHero == null) // error
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to allow looking up an attribute would be to use a Dictionary, though it will require a unique key.

So, you would need to map your objects into the dictionary. Here is a sample console app to demonstrate:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class Hero
    {
        public Hero(int price, int points)
        {
            Price = price;
            Points = points;
        }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int Points { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var heros = new Dictionary<string, Hero>();
            heros.Add("Hero1 Name", new Hero(10, 100));
            heros.Add("Hero2 Name", new Hero(11, 101));
            heros.Add("Hero3 Name", new Hero(12, 102));

            if (heros.ContainsKey("Hero1 Name"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(heros["Hero1 Name"].Price);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need a List of Heroes of some sort. This list need to be accessible from the form constructor, and from the click event.

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
   Hero[] data = new []{
        new Hero{ Name= "Foo"},
        new Hero{ Name= "Bar", Price=100, Dps=20, PropertyName=Value},
   };

   public Form1(){
   // ...
   }
// ...
}
```

At initialisation you will create the button based on your listing of heroes.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    // Have a Container that will hold the buttons
    foreach(var hero in data){
        var button = new Button();
        //set text // set size 
        // set position. Compute it based on button size you just set.

        // We put the whole hero in the tag not just the name `button.Tag = hero.Name`
        button.Tag = hero;
        
        // Add one even for all the button.
        button.Click += new EventHandler(HeroButton_Click);
        
        //Add button to the container
        this.Controls.Add(button); // This or a container. 
    }
}
```

And  the event that will be handle all the button click:

```
private void HeroButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button) sender; 
    var hero = (Hero)btn.Tag    
    // Do thing with the Hero.

   //Old Way, we search for the Hero in the list Data
    // var hero = data.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Name == (string)btn.Tag);   
    // if(hero==null) ; // error, could not find the hero

}
```

Comment: How can i use your list ? You used Name:"boo" for example, if i want to put (In order : Name,Price,Dps ) : Skarl, 100, 5. How can i do ?

Comment: List have to be accessible from both `Form1` and `HeroButton_Click` make it a property of Form1. And you seems to be asking about simple object object initalisation `new Hero{ Name= "Foo", Price=100, Dps=20, PropertyName=Value}`

Comment: here is the documetation on onject initalisation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-initialize-objects-by-using-an-object-initializer

Comment: okay thanks, now i'm having trouble with the var hero = data.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Name..), it tells me an error with the x.Name.

Comment: Could you give me the error message? Does Hero has a property named `Name`? Is this property public? Is that `Name` property the same type of the thing on the other side of the Equals?

Comment: Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the right hand side to type 'type'

Comment: on the other side it says the same, and i declared name as public string Name{get;set;} In your code you put ==, its = instead?

Comment: Ok that's because TAg property is an object  [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag?view=net-5.0). So you need to cast it to string Like `data.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Name == (string)btn.Tag)`.

Comment: Not it's `==` that a comparaison. It means give me the first element in Data where Name match the tag. But as Tag can be object we can simply store the hero in there. and save one lookup. editing my answer to reflect that simplification

Comment: last questions (I hope), if I have later on 65 heroes, I'll need to place 65 buttons manually ? And to access to my property i only need to write hero.Price, for example right ?

Comment: If you have more heroes, you simply need to add them in the list. The second code block show how to programmatically populate a container with button with only a list as input.

Comment: Yes but i need 1 button per heroes (i'm trying to make a little heroe clicker and I try to understand how to make easier code if i want to implant new things). That's why i asked you if I had to manually position my 65 buttons

Comment: As I stated the Second block of code Create a button `var button = new Button();` . Then you can 
you can size it `button .Size = new Size(50, 100);`. Choose it's position `button.Location = new Point(70,70);`.
 Add the click event `button.Click += new EventHandler(HeroButton_Click);`. Then add it to the container `containerName.Controls.Add(button);` or `this.Controls.Add(button);`

Comment: You just need a counter and compute the position based on the size. 1rst button at (0,0) 2nd at (size + marging,0), 3rd at ((size+marging) *2),0) etc etc

Comment: thank you a lot for your patience and explanation :)

Comment: Here is a code that will help you position and place button https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426888/dynamic-button-creation-placing-them-in-a-predefined-order-using-c-sharp. It used a TableLayoutPanel Control, so you don't have to compute position simply loop and add them in row column*

Comment: You can also use FlowLayoutPanel it will make it like a flex box. But it can be weird if the button size is not normalized. If you plan of having more than a few hero I will recommend using a Id property. You will soon be tired of typing `"Jörmungandr"` and will be glad to deal with HeroN°27 instead. It will alsomake localization easier as you can translate the data without impacting the code.

Comment: Can i get somewhere else to text you ? if its not too much to ask :)

Comment: No, sorry. It will be more beneficial if you continue using the site. Because I don't know everything, and may not have time. Please simply ask on SO. Following the guide line [ask] and [mre]. You will find that trying to express an issue clearly, will simply solve 90% of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could just store each hero in the `.Tag()` property of each button.  Associate them in the `Load()` event of the form (assuming WinForms):

```
private Heroe Heroe1 = new Heroe(100,5);
private Heroe Heroe2 = new Heroe(500,10);
private Heroe Heroe3 = new Heroe(100,40);

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnHeroe1.Tag = Heroe1;
    btnHeroe2.Tag = Heroe2;
    btnHeroe3.Tag = Heroe3;
}
```

Now you can just grab that hero from the tag:

```
Button b = sender as Button;
Heroe H = (Heroe)b.Tag;
// ... do something with "H" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that for with a String. You could use the **Tag**-property on your **Button** to achieve it!