# Arranging controls in Winforms TableLayoutPanel

Tags: winforms

I'm adding controls to Winforms TableLayoutPanel using `panel.Controls.Add(control)` at runtime.

I need to arrange the controls in two columns with variable number of rows by first filling the first and then the second column to achieve the following layout:

```
C1 C4
C2 C5
C3 C6
```

No matter how I configure the panel it is always populated in the following order:

```
C1 C2
C3 C4
C5 C6
```

How can I change the order of control insertion?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33969228/3110834) or [the other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34426939/3110834) to learn how you can arrange controls in a grid layout at run-time.

Comment: And of course consider using DataGridView if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the second overload of tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add() in order to pass the row and column index:
`public virtual void Add(Control control, int column, int row`);

**EXAMPLE:**

```
private void SetTableLayoutPanel()
{
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear();
    tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2;
    tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 3;
    tableLayoutPanel1.CellBorderStyle = TableLayoutPanelCellBorderStyle.Single;

    var counter = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount; j++)
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Text = "C" + counter;
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b, i, j);

            counter++;
        }               
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]